# cannot use obsolete binding at ‘input’ because it has a destructor

Tags: c++

here's the word-count I wrote. I got this error: `cannot use obsolete binding at ‘input’ because it has a destructor` and `error: name lookup of ‘input’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping` what are they suppose to mean? thanks in advance.

```
   //rewrite the word-count program using insert instead of subscripting
    #include <iostream>
    #include <utility>
    #include <map>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
        cout<<"please enter some words"<<endl;
        map<string,int> word_count;
        for(string input; cin>>input; )
            if(!word_count.insert(make_pair(input,1)).second);
                ++word_count[input];
        for(map<string,int>::iterator iter=word_count.begin(); iter!=word_count.end(); ++iter)
            cout<<iter->first<<": "<<iter->second<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove ; from

if(!word_count.insert(make_pair(input,1)).second);

In general try to use {}, makes your code more readable, maintenable.

Answer (score 4):

```
    for(string input; cin>>input; )
        if(!word_count.insert(make_pair(input,1)).second);
            ++word_count[input];
```

That semicolon after the `if` ends the `if` block. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
    for(string input; cin>>input; )
    {
        if(!word_count.insert(make_pair(input,1)).second)
        {}
    }
    ++word_count[input];
```

The scope of `input` is that of the `for` loop, and you are trying to use it outside of it.